# Draw line screen and device independent

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am working on an application designed both for Android and iOS using Xamarin; but this is not relevant for the question itself.

One feature of the app is to let the user draw a sort of sketch on the screen.

Let's take a simple line as example: using the finger the user can draw a line where they are moving their finger. To do this we use the specific device methods for iOS & Android:

#### iOS

```
public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
  UITouch touch = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;
  CGPoint currentPointiOS = touch.LocationInView(MainView);
}
```

#### Android

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
 Point currentPointAndroid = new Point((int) e.GetX(), (int) e.GetY());
}
```

`currentPointIOS` is defined in points and `currentPointAndroid` is defined in pixels.

Once the line (which is a group of points, not iOS points but geometric points with x and y coordinates) is drawn we send this to a server and then this can be viewed from an Android or an iOS device.

Is there a way to store the data about the line in an absolute way so it can be shown in correctly on other devices with different resolutions? Is there a way to convert the Android pixel to the iOS point (if this could be useful)?

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: I think you should ask "Can the geometric point be converted to iOS point and Android pixels?" The answer is - you convert pixels and points to geometric points to store. You should be able to convert it back. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems you would also have to scale to device size, IOW if someone draws on a Android tablet or large screen phone, and they draw outside the bounds of a smaller screen, how then will it show up on a smaller screen? Not to mention different aspect ratios, i.e draws in Landscape then renders in portrait. Do you care if the aspect ratio changes, IOW the image will get squished on one axis? You will need to do some math and perhaps store your point as a relative value to screen dimensions. IOW a point in the middle of the screen would be x=.5, y= .5 as a fraction of screen width/height.

Comment: Thanks @YuriS but I think that geometric point can't work because as

Comment: Thanks @YuriS but I think that geometric point can't work because as jgoldberger said I need to take care about different screens. I'd like that if I draw a rect in a screen with resolution of 800x600 this will appear as a rect also in a 1000x700 screen even if aspect ratio is different. I am wondering if exists some sort of language/strategy to achieve this. I need some way to save a geometric path with can work for android/ios and which is screen independent, it seems strange to me that something like this doesn't exist.

Comment: It should not be that difficult to convert a point you get from a user's drawing into a point that is a fraction of the width and height of the view. IOW you get a point at x=100, y=100 in a view that is 800x600. You would store this as x=100/800=1/8=.125, x=100/600=1/6=.1667 (rounded up). Then to place the point in a 1000x700 view you would convert the stored fraction onto a point, i.e. x=.125*1000, y=.1667*700. And generally a line is stored as two points, the x,y point at start of the line and the x,y point at the end of the line.